# Silverlight, best way to keep a log file

Tags: c#, silverlight, text, web

I'm working on a silverlight project, I would like to write some text to a log file everytime there is a delete or submit on the website.

I would like to keep the file on the server side.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you using on the server side? That's where the logging happens, so that's the real question here. (the fact that the client is Silverlight is almost irrelevant)

Comment: I'm using Azure with a WCF service and a Sql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different strategies with which you can do logging in Silverlight - Client, Server OR Both Client and Server. You can also make use of IIS to handle logging Silverlight errors for you.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/12/03/error-logging-in-silverlight-2-with-iis-and-the-isolated-storage.aspx) is a detailed article on how to do logging in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard loggers like log4net or NLog.